# iPhone Creating a Modal Movie Window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, xcode4, modal-dialog

I have created an app that incorporates a table view, detail view, and a web view.  I have established a cell in the table view that takes a URL from an RSS feed and will display it in a webview.  The URL is an .MP4 file which causes the video to play.  The problem I am having is that when the video ends, I cannot go back to the previous screen. The code is below:

DetailViewController.m load webview

```
if (indexPath.section == SectionHeader && indexPath.row == SectionHeaderEnclosure) {  
    if (item.enclosures) {  
        for (NSDictionary *dict in item.enclosures){  
            NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];  
            NSLog(@" url is : %@",url);  

            //EXPERIMENTAL              
            WebViewController *webVC = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
            [self presentModalViewController:webVC animated:YES];

        }  
    }  
}
```

WebViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self.view = webView;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_url]]];

}

//Dismiss modal view
- (IBAction) done:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"done:");
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use an MPMoviePlayerViewController. The documentation shows how to set it up with the URL directly using `initWithContentURL:` and present it modally.  You can listen for notifications thet the movie has ended and dismiss it when done.  Lots of good stuff in the documentation.

Comment: Don't have time to write out the code but this link shows everything you need to know: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Oh I noticed I should have said MPMoviePlayerViewController in my answer.  Its updated now.

Comment: initWithContentURL is specifically for URL's.  You need to specifically pass in an NSURL not just a string.